# phpmyadmin column headers repeated more times when browsing table

Tags: phpmyadmin

i have noticed that when you scroll down a browsing table (more than 100 records) the column headers repeat themselves automatically. Here is a picture:

[db Browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Clu.png)

Is there a way to eliminate this behavior (red circled one) from the browsing page? Is it a bug?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Don't add image link, rather attach the image itself

Comment: Canot do that..